# how to fix matrix error Issue in r markdown?

Tags: r, matrix, r-markdown

Rmarkdown keeps telling me this whenever I try to load r file :
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': cannot open the connection

this is what the r file contains:

```
a <- as.matrix(read.csv("data/a_a.csv", row.names = 1))
b  <- as.matrix(read.csv("data/b_b.csv" , row.names = 1))
```

Comment: I think this is not about R-markdown; if this runs normally on the R console and differently when rendering a `.Rmd` file, then I check paths, check pre-existing objects in the global environment, and then [edit] your question to make it reproducible.

Comment: This works: `data(iris); write.csv(iris, "a_a.csv",row.names = F); a <- as.matrix(read.csv("a_a.csv"))`. Is there something going on with the path / filesystem?

Comment: I solved it.  In the R file, you would want to show the entire path ex:  a <- as.matrix(read.csv("project/R/data/a_a.csv", row.names = 1)).      This way Rmarkdown was able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

In the R file, you would want to show the entire path example:

`a <- as.matrix(read.csv("project/R/data/a_a.csv", row.names = 1))`.

when you load it into Rmarkdown, it will be able to read it.

Thanks!